# Aptana: show unused css-class in .css files

Tags: css, class, aptana

is there a way "plug in" that shows unused css - classes.
I know there are other tools. but i´am intresting to find those in aptana studio over a hole projekt.

Answer (score 0):

http://unused-css.com/

Use this web tool to detect unused classes!